# How to count the number of even integers in a list in Haskell with State monad?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to grok some of the fundamentals of the State Monad in Haskell, by constructing my own examples.

Consider a simple example where I want to count the number of even integers in an array of integers. Sure this can be done very easily using pure functions, but I wanted to try the round-about State monad route, where we keep a counter that keeps incrementing for every element that has been checked.

Here is a partial (but obviously  wrong) attempt that I have managed to come up with thus far.

```
import Control.Monad.State

f' :: [Int] -> State Int [Int]
f' []     = state (\s -> ([],s)) 
f' (x:xs) = if x `mod` 2 == 0 then state (\s -> ((x:xs), s+1)) -- how can I fix this line? 
            else f' xs
```

This code compiles, but clearly does not give the right answer. How then can I fix this code, to do something similar to the following Python code

```
counter = 0 # incremented when we encounter an even integer.
for elt in integer_list:
   if elt % 2 == 0 :
      counter = counter + 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answer starts from scratch to build up an implementation. I think it is also worth seeing a minimal change to your existing code to make it sensible. We will even keep your existing type -- though the other answer proposes that it be changed, I think it is acceptable (if not great).

In my opinion, the real problem is that you have recursed only in one branch of your `if`. What we really want is to recurse whether or not the current element is even. So:

```
f' (x:xs) = do
    if x `mod` 2 == 0 then state (\s -> ((), s+1)) -- increase the count by one
                      else state (\s -> ((), s  )) -- don't increase the count by one
    rest <- f' xs -- compute the answer for the rest of the list
    return (x:rest) -- reconstruct the answer for the whole list
```

We can check that it does the right thing in ghci:

```
> runState (f' [1..5]) 0
([1,2,3,4,5],2)
```

This is just about the smallest change you can make to get your implementation idea working.

From there, I would suggest a number of refactorings. First, your pervasive use of `state` is a code smell. I would write the various uses in this way instead:

```
f' [] = return []
f' (x:xs) = do
    if x `mod` 2 == 0 then modify (+1) else return ()
    rest <- f' xs
    return (x:rest)
```

From here, I would use the `even` function in the conditional, and notice that the `when` function implements the "do some action or `return ()`" operation. So:

```
f' [] = return []
f' (x:xs) = do
    when (even x) (modify (+1))
    rest <- f' xs
    return (x:rest)
```

Additionally, we actually have a combinator for running a monadic action on each element of a list; that is `mapM`. So we can turn the above explicit recursion into an implicit one in this way:

```
f' xs = mapM (\x -> when (even x) (modify (+1)) >> return x) xs
```

Finally, I think it a little bit odd that the function returns the list it consumed. Not *unidiomatic*, per se, as the previous objections have been, but maybe not what you want. If it turns out that you don't plan on using the resulting list in any followup computation, it will be more efficient to throw it away as you go; and the `mapM_` combinator does this. So:

```
f' :: [Int] -> State Int ()
f' xs = mapM_ (\x -> when (even x) (modify (+1))) xs
```

At this point, I would consider `f'` to be quite a nice implementation of the idea you have proposed.

Comment: maybe even nicer as follows ;)       f' :: [Int] -> State Int ()
f' = mapM_ (\x -> when (even x) (modify (+1)))

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed explanations!

Answer (score 3):

Let's get back to the drawing board. The actual function you want to use is something like

```
countEven :: [Int] -> Int
countEven xs = runStateMagic xs
```

where `runStateMagic` uses some `State` hidden in its depths. How could that function look like? Well, it has to use either `execState` or `evalState`. Since we're interested in the state only (aka, our current count of numbers), so let's replace `runStateMagic` with `execState`:

```
countEven :: [Int] -> Int
countEven xs = execState someState 0
```

Now, `execState`'s type fixes our `stateFunc` to `State Int a`. The actual value type of the state is arbitrary, since we're not going to use it anyway. So what should `someState` do? It should probably work on the list, and use `modify' (+1)` if we have an even number. Let's write a helper for that:

```
increaseIfEven :: Int -> State Int ()
increaseIfEven n
  | even n    = modify' inc
  | otherwise = return ()
```

This will now modify the state iff the number was even. All we have to do is to apply this to every element on the list. Therefore, for a list `xs`, we can simply do

```
mapM_ increaseIfEven xs
```

Remember, `mapM_ :: (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m ()`. But in our case, that `m` is `State Int`, so it already contains our counter.

All in all, we end up with

```
countEven :: [Int] -> Int
countEven xs = execState (mapM_ increaseIfEven xs) 0
```

But keep in mind: the important part was to fix the type of the original function, `f'`.

Comment: @ Zeta Wow! Thank you so much! I wish I could accept both answers. I marked the other one, since it built of my solution but this answer was extremely useful too. Thanks again for the detailed response!